# how to begin NSWindow in fullscreen

Tags: macos, fullscreen, nswindow

I am developing an app for Mac OSX in Xcode5

and I want to display my first Window in fullscreen (no toolbar just my view)

I found a way to display a button on the corner for fullscreen:

AppDelegate.m:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    screenFrame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];

    [self.window setBackgroundColor: NSColor.whiteColor];
    [self.window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary];
    [[self window] setFrame:screenFrame display:YES];
}
```

but to get fullscreen I have to click on the corner's button

[image]

how to get fullscreen saving the step of pressing that button?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

add this [self.window toggleFullScreen:self];

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    screenFrame = [[NSScreen mainScreen] frame];

    [self.window setBackgroundColor: NSColor.whiteColor];
    [self.window setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary];
    [self.window setFrame:screenFrame display:YES];
    [self.window toggleFullScreen:self];
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Swift Version:

```
let screenFrame = NSScreen.main?.frame
self.window?.collectionBehavior = NSWindow.CollectionBehavior.fullScreenPrimary
self.window?.setFrame(screenFrame!, display: true)
self.window?.toggleFullScreen(self)
```