# Beginner stuck with a problem with NSScreen.screens

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift4

I'm a beginner with swift and I'm learning as I go with a project for myself. Right now, I'm trying to make a "kiosk mode" window appear that maximizes to fill the entire screen while the menu bar and dock are hidden so the app can't be exited (This for a procrastination app by the way). However, after getting everything working, I'm having a problem as the space that was taken up by the menubar now has a gap that I need filled ([see pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AVZx.jpg)). Because of this gap, the user is able to click the gap and exit the app which I'm trying to prevent. Ive done a lot of searching on here and I can't find a solution, I'd really appreciate any help I could get with this.

Note: I'm working with Swift 4.1 and Xcode 9.4.1

```
import Cocoa

typealias NSRect = CGRect

class MainWindowController: NSWindowController {

    convenience init() {

        self.init(windowNibName: NSNib.Name(rawValue: "MainWindowController"))

    }

    override func windowDidLoad() {

        super.windowDidLoad()

        NSMenu.setMenuBarVisible(false)

        NSApp.presentationOptions = [.hideDock, .hideMenuBar, .disableForceQuit, .disableProcessSwitching,.autoHideToolbar]

        window?.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.754)

        window?.isOpaque = false

        window?.setFrame(NSScreen.screens[0].frame, display: true, animate: false)

        window?.styleMask.remove(.titled)

    }

}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up Kiosk Mode for Mac apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32809974/how-to-set-up-kiosk-mode-for-mac-apps)

Comment: @Willeke thanks for the suggestion! I actually already took a look at that thread but it still produced the gap at the top.

Comment: have you tried [how to begin NSWindow in fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24145269/how-to-begin-nswindow-in-fullscreen)?

Answer (score 0):

An improved version of your windowDidLoad function would look something like this:

```
override func windowDidLoad() {
        
        super.windowDidLoad()
        
        NSMenu.setMenuBarVisible(false)
        NSApp.presentationOptions = [.hideDock, .hideMenuBar, .disableForceQuit, .disableProcessSwitching]
        window?.backgroundColor = NSColor(red: 1, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 0.754)
        window?.isOpaque = false
        window?.styleMask.remove(.titled)
        window?.setFrame(NSScreen.screens[0].frame, display: true, animate: false)
        
    }
```

You need to remove the window title bar before setting the frame, because the title bar exists until you hide it. Also, you probably don't need to autohide the toolbar.

I would replace your presentation options with `window?.level = .mainMenu + 1`, then you wouldn't have to hide the menu bar and all of that stuff, but you don't have to.

Comment: Thank you so much! the gap is fixed now but I've actually run into another problem with your solution if you wouldn't mind pointing me in the right dircection.Ive noticed that now the window can be "clicked through" (not sure if this is correct terminology), and any app behind my window (or finder) can be clicked and then the app can be force quitted from there. Do you know how I can solve this?

Comment: I found an option : `window.styleMask = []`

Comment: You can also leave out `window?.styleMask.remove(.titled)`